# How to capture user information during related model's update using inlineformset factory

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms, inline-formset

I am trying to save user ID in the model's relevant field on create as well as update of a pair of related models.

Following are the objects, albeit truncated for better readability:

## models.py

```
class Plant(BaseTimeStampModel):
    # ....

class Calendar(BaseTimeStampModel):
    calendar_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=4)
    short_text = models.CharField(max_length=55, ...
    # ...


class AssignedPlants(BaseTimeStampModel):
    assginment_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=4, ...
    plant = models.ForeignKey(primary_key=True...
    calendar = models.ForeignKey(Calendar, related_name= ...
    short_text = models.CharField(max_length=55, ...
    # ...
```

## forms.py

```
class CreateCalendarForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Calendar
        fields = (...

class CreatePlantAssgnForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CreatePlantAssgnForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.auto_id = True

    class Meta:
        model = AssignedPlants
        fields = ...
    exclude = ()

CreateCalendarFormset = inlineformset_factory(
    Calendar,
    AssignedPlants,
    form = CreatePlantAssgnForm,
    extra=0,
    can_delete=True, min_num=1, validate_min=True, max_num=50, validate_max=True,
    )
```

## views.py

```
class CalendarCreateView(CreateView):
    template_name = ...
    model = Calendar
    form_class = CreateCalendarForm

    success_url = ...

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(CalendarCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            data['calendar'] = CreateCalendarFormset(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)
        else:
            data['calendar'] = CreateCalendarFormset()
        return data

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
        context = self.get_context_data()
        calendar = context['calendar']

        with transaction.atomic():
            if calendar.is_valid():
                self.object = form.save()
                calendar.instance = self.object

                for frmst_form in calendar.forms:
                    f = frmst_form.save(commit=False)
                    f.created_by = self.request.user
                    calendar.save()
                    f.save()

                return redirect(...

            else:
                context.update({'calendar': calendar})
                return self.render_to_response(context)
        return super(CalendarCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

With this arrangement I am able to save the user ID creating the new record (**both in the parent as well child tables**).

While changing (updating), I am trying to fashion my view like this (rest of the stuff remaining similar):

```
# ...
        with transaction.atomic():
            if calendar.is_valid():
                self.object = form.save()
                calendar.instance = self.object

                for frmst_form in calendar.forms:
                    f = frmst_form.save(commit=False)
                    f.changed_by = self.request.user    # Field "changed_by" to be updated
                    calendar.save()
                    f.save()

                return redirect(...
# ...
```

So here while an existing record is changed, I want that both the model's "changed_by" field also be updated with the user ID.

However, the "changed_by" field in the DB's **child table** "AssignedPlants" shows "NULL" (the parent table's field value gets updated, though).

**WHAT I am doing wrong? How do I update the "changed_by" values at "UPDATE" (for child model as well)?**

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue. Was rather easy doing it in model save().

Thank you all for help rendered.